# input field in javascript file

Tags: javascript, forms, input

How can I make input box in JS file. This JS create right-click menu with three links. I would add forth with input for name (mytext) including in dynamic link.

Example. Link is: www.mypage.com?name=mytext
I want to have in this menu input box and button "search"

my code of this three links is:

```
function prepare_menu_content(e, t, n) {
  var r = "<div class='mwmenu'>";
  r = r + "<a class='point' href='/mapa/mapa.php?lat=" + e + "&lng=" + t + "&promien=5'>What is here?</a>";
  r = r + "<pre><a class='km' href='/mapa/mapa.php?lat=" + e + "&lng=" + t + "&promien=20'>What is around 20 km?</a></pre>";
  r = r + "<a class='add' href='/mapa/dodaj-punkt.php?lat=" + e + "&lng=" + t + "&zoom=" + n + "'>Add point here</a>";
  return r + "</div>"
}

function showContextMenu2(e) {
  mwmenu.setPosition(e);
  mwmenu.setContent(prepare_menu_content(e.lat().toFixed(6), e.lng().toFixed(6), mapa.getZoom()));
  mwmenu.open(mapa)
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code into a GitHub gist or something so we can see it in a more readable form?

Comment: Do we guess what `e` `t` `n` are? Possible you can format your code too. Also I don't really understand what it is you're asking.... Are you wanting to know how to get `name=` from the url?

Comment: There's this new thing the kids are using called carriage returns (and spaces).  Makes your code human-readable, which is useful when you want humans to read it.

Comment: @NewToJS this is a js file. it make a small right click menu in map (look at http://www.mapa.okiem.pl  - polish page - but right click on the map). values are not important in this question. I just need to ad fourth position in menu just before </div> - where will be an input box. This value will be use in link for another search.

Comment: I just did it - my fault - I was looking for very hard answer, but it was simple. Sorry.